# Avoid generating N+1 queries while fetching an object graph through ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ancestry

I have two Models: AssetItem and Title.

- An AssetItem belongs to a Title / Title has many asset_items.
- A Title can have a parent Title (thereby creating a hierarchy); this parent/child  relationship within Titles is managed by the ancestry gem.

I've got a controller that is fetching a bunch of AssetItems.  Those AssetItems should come with their Title, that Title's parent, and *that* Title's parent and so on.  In the end, the controller presents this object graph in JSON.  I am trying to find a way to eager-load all of the title hierarchy for a given asset item.

I am doing this in my controller:

```
def show
  asset_items = AssetItem.includes(:title).where(:id => list_of_ids)
  eager_load_titles_for(asset_items)
  respond_with asset_items, serializer: AssetItemSerializer
end

private

def eager_load_titles_for(asset_items)
  title_ids = asset_items.map { |a| a.title.ancestor_ids }.flatten
  Title.find(title_ids) # these titles are not really used, this is just to eager load them
end
```

The idea is, that a collection of asset items are fetched and then the title ids associated with those asset items are simply loaded (but not used), so that when the serializer does something like object.parent.parent.parent.some_attribute, it gets that Title from the cache, not the db.

However, the results in the log do not match my expectations:

```
10:19:27 web.1    |   AssetItem Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "asset_items".* FROM "asset_items" WHERE "asset_items"."id" IN (291, 311, 316, 309, 323, 304, 296, 289, 328, 284, 373, 342, 330, 335, 361, 366, 354, 347, 359, 380, 400, 405, 392, 378, 397, 417, 412, 385, 436, 429, 450, 448, 431, 455, 462, 424, 443, 481, 498, 467, 501, 493, 474, 506, 486, 479, 532, 525, 520, 513)
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" IN (167, 182, 188, 203, 227, 242, 248, 263, 284, 299, 305, 320, 341, 356, 377, 392, 398, 413, 434, 449, 455, 470, 491, 506, 515, 530, 551, 566, 587, 602, 608, 623, 644, 659, 665, 680, 701, 716, 737, 752, 758, 773, 794, 809, 818, 833, 854, 875, 890, 911)
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" IN (186, 187, 246, 247, 261, 262, 240, 241, 282, 283, 225, 226, 201, 202, 180, 181, 297, 298, 165, 166, 432, 433, 339, 340, 303, 304, 318, 319, 396, 397, 411, 412, 375, 376, 354, 355, 390, 391, 453, 454, 513, 514, 528, 529, 489, 490, 447, 448, 504, 505, 564, 565, 549, 550, 468, 469, 621, 622, 600, 601, 663, 664, 657, 658, 606, 607, 678, 679, 699, 700, 585, 586, 642, 643, 756, 757, 807, 808, 714, 715, 816, 817, 792, 793, 735, 736, 831, 832, 771, 772, 750, 751, 909, 910, 888, 889, 873, 874, 852, 853)
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "asset_items".* FROM "asset_items" WHERE "asset_items"."id" IN (291, 311, 316, 309, 323, 304, 296, 289, 328, 284, 373, 342, 330, 335, 361, 366, 354, 347, 359, 380, 400, 405, 392, 378, 397, 417, 412, 385, 436, 429, 450, 448, 431, 455, 462, 424, 443, 481, 498, 467, 501, 493, 474, 506, 486, 479, 532, 525, 520, 513)
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" IN (167, 182, 188, 203, 227, 242, 248, 263, 284, 299, 305, 320, 341, 356, 377, 392, 398, 413, 434, 449, 455, 470, 491, 506, 515, 530, 551, 566, 587, 602, 608, 623, 644, 659, 665, 680, 701, 716, 737, 752, 758, 773, 794, 809, 818, 833, 854, 875, 890, 911)
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" IN (186, 187, 246, 247, 261, 262, 240, 241, 282, 283, 225, 226, 201, 202, 180, 181, 297, 298, 165, 166, 432, 433, 339, 340, 303, 304, 318, 319, 396, 397, 411, 412, 375, 376, 354, 355, 390, 391, 453, 454, 513, 514, 528, 529, 489, 490, 447, 448, 504, 505, 564, 565, 549, 550, 468, 469, 621, 622, 600, 601, 663, 664, 657, 658, 606, 607, 678, 679, 699, 700, 585, 586, 642, 643, 756, 757, 807, 808, 714, 715, 816, 817, 792, 793, 735, 736, 831, 832, 771, 772, 750, 751, 909, 910, 888, 889, 873, 874, 852, 853)
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 186]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
```

As you can see, initially title ID 186, and 187 are loaded in the where clause here:

```
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" IN (186, 187, 246, 247, 261, 262, 240, 241, 282, 283, 225, 226, 201, 202, 180, 181, 297, 298, 165, 166, 432, 433, 339, 340, 303, 304, 318, 319, 396, 397, 411, 412, 375, 376, 354, 355, 390, 391, 453, 454, 513, 514, 528, 529, 489, 490, 447, 448, 504, 505, 564, 565, 549, 550, 468, 469, 621, 622, 600, 601, 663, 664, 657, 658, 606, 607, 678, 679, 699, 700, 585, 586, 642, 643, 756, 757, 807, 808, 714, 715, 816, 817, 792, 793, 735, 736, 831, 832, 771, 772, 750, 751, 909, 910, 888, 889, 873, 874, 852, 853)
```

and then below that, we see again:

```
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 186]]
10:19:27 web.1    |   Title Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 187]]
```

And that is why I am wondering what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you even calling `eager_load_titles_for`, when the `includes` is already doing the eagerloading?

Comment: Does your `Title` record have an association for its ancestors?

Comment: @omarvelous - because when the serializer is doing asset_item.title.parent.parent.parent.foo, it was causing the database to load.  eager_load_titles_for was an attempt to preload that title by finding parents up the hierarchical chain and getting activerecord to cache them

Comment: @carlosramireziii - Title has_ancestry (and an ancestry column), and has_many :asset_items

Comment: Have we identified what exactly is causing the n+1, is it the view when you call `object.parent.parent.parent.some_attribute` or the `ancestor_ids` in `eager_load_titles_for`?

Comment: it's the "view", i.e., the serializer preparing a JSON response.  It is calling the attribute on a parent that is potentially way high up in the hierarchy chain, and therefore needs to be eagerly loaded along with the asset_item...  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Gotcha... it's odd that it's not using the prior loaded Titles... I wonder if the way it's calling it has anything to do with it? The `[["id", 186]]` is new to me... Do we know if it's either `Ancestry` or the `serializer`? I wonder if you run `object.parent.parent.parent.some_attribute` in the console if you get similar issue?

Comment: The [["id", 186"]] is just interpolation...  From the rails console, if I do: "Title.find(186)", then I will see: Title Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "titles".* FROM "titles" WHERE "titles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 186]]

Comment: Oh and, I don't get the behavior in the console because it appears nothing gets cached...  If I just do Title.find(1) over and over, it always says Title Load, never cache.

Comment: I meant by doing it in the console, at least you can see if it is running n+1 queries to fetch titles in a object's ancestry. That might (super stretch) be an indicator that it is (not) Ancestry gem?